# Verify that file is not caching

Tags: nginx, cache

I have this code in nginx:

```
location / {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  autoindex on;

  set $no_cache "";

  if ($request_uri ~* \.m3u8$) {
    set $no_cache "1";
  }

  proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
  proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
}
```

I want to verify that the caching is working correctly. How do I do that?

I have tried a curl command, but it doesn't seem to give me the info I need:

```
curl --head -v http://myurl.myloc.com/myfile.m3u8
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're talking about Nginx page caching. I'm also going to assume you've set page caching up correctly.

In this case I would take the simple approach to test for non-caching

1. Delete the current cache
2. Make a request for a file that shouldn't be cached
3. Count the files in the cache directory structure

To test for cached files

1. Delete the current cache
2. Make a request for a file that should be cached
3. Count the files in the cache directory structure

One way to see what have executed within your Nginx config us to use the headers_more module, which you build into Nginx ([tutorial here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source)), then use the "add_header" directive throughout your config - remove it for production. You appear to be using add_header already, so you may be ok. Then you can simply see with a "curl -i" which parts of your config executed. For example

```
location / {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  autoindex on;

  set $no_cache "";

  if ($request_uri ~* \.m3u8$) {
    set $no_cache "1";
    add_header EXAMPLE_HEADER "abcd";
  }
  add_header NO_CACHE $no_cache;

  proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
  proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
}
```

A curl -i for a file ending in "m3u8" would include something like this

Header: NO_CACHE 1

whereas others would say

Header: NO_CACHE

That's a very simple but powerful technique I use a lot when getting complex Nginx configs working.